# Eager loading has_one through rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

I have relations. I want to get title of series like this `article.series.title` . To prevent N+1, I’m using preload association data.

I tried `Article.includes(:series)` or `Article.includes(:article_series)`, but it seems not working

```rb
class Article 
  has_one :article_series, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :series, through: :article_series
end

class ArticleSeries 
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :series
end

class Series
  has_many :article_series
end
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Do you want query by ONE article or many? If you want all the series title from ONE article, do `article.series.pluck(:title)`. In that case, you don't care about N+1 queries because you are querying by the series from one single article.